# How to get the street address as title for marker

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Following is my code..

fetchlastlocation() is a method which is called when gps icon(imageView) is clicked. This code works but I want to get/fetch the street address and attach it to marker title.
What should I do to get this result?

```
 private void fetchlastlocation() {
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]
                    {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);

            return;
        }
        Task<Location> task=fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location1) {
                if(location1!=null){
                    currentlocation=location1;

                    LatLng latLng=new LatLng(currentlocation.getLatitude(),currentlocation.getLongitude());
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions=new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
                    nMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
                    nMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,50));
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Geocoder to get the address from latlong

```
public static String getCountryName(Context context, double latitude, double longitude) {
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = null;
try {
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    Address result;

    if (addresses != null && !addresses.isEmpty()) {
        return addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
       //     String city = addresses[0].locality;
       //     String state = addresses[0].adminArea;
      //      String country = addresses[0].countryName;
      //      String postalCode = addresses[0].postalCode;
      //      String knownName = addresses[0].featureName;
    }
    return null;
} catch (IOException ignored) {
   //do something
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What You want to do is called reverse  Geocoding. [check docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder)

Since you already have your geographic coordinates (lattitude and longitude) use them with the Geocoder class to lookup a human readable address that you want